# Apache with PHP running CGI mode: The php executable processes itself, what do I need to change in the config

Tags: php, apache-2.4, configuration, httpd.conf

I'm trying to install a pre-Iraq-Surge **4.4.9 PHP** in a modern **Apache 2.4.6** and want to run it in CGI mode.

The current configuration is as follows:

The PHP executable is `/usr/local/php-4.4.9/bin/php`

A test file exists in `$documentroot/phphere/index.php` of the virtual server, it contains:

```
<?php
 phpinfo();
?>
```

If I execute the `index.php` using `php`, all is hunky dory.

Running

```
/usr/local/php-4.4.9/bin/php $documentroot/phphere/index.php | less
```

yields

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/4.4.9
Content-type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html><head>
<style type="text/css">
body {background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000;}
body, td, th, h1, h2 {font-family: sans-serif;}
pre {margin: 0px; font-family: monospace;}
a:link {color: #000099; text-decoration: none; background-color: #
```

etc.

Excellent!

However, calling `index.php` via a web client results in this:

```
Warning: Unexpected character in input: '' (ASCII=1) state=1 in /usr/local/php-4.4.9/bin/php on line 277

Warning: Unexpected character in input: '' (ASCII=15) state=1 in /usr/local/php-4.4.9/bin/php on line 277

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /usr/local/php-4.4.9/bin/php on line 277
```

which is exactly the output that one gets if **one processes the php executable with itself**, i.e. the output of

```
/usr/local/php-4.4.9/bin/php /usr/local/php-4.4.9/bin/php
```

(less any headers additionally generated).

Ok, so there is some problem in the Apache setup. But what?

The following is configured:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php        .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

ScriptAlias /outsidephp             /usr/local/php-4.4.9/bin
Action      application/x-httpd-php /outsidephp/php
```

If I understand correctly, [AddType](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype) tags any file ending in `.php` with MIME type `application/x-httpd-php`.

If PHP shall be run via CGI conventions, then the executable to run whenever a file with the MIME type `application/x-httpd-php` is requested is indicated with [Action](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_actions.html#action). The [ScriptAlias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#scriptalias) gives an URL-path to the directory in which the `php` executable can be found. (This syntax sounds awkward though, why not have a single command for that?)

Additionally, the option `ExecCGI` has been set in the directory containing `index.php` and the SELinux contexts on that filesystem tree are marked with `httpd_sys_script_exec_t`.

Note that there is **absolutely no**

```
AddHandler cgi-script .php
```

in the configuration because THAT make Apache try to execute files ending in `.php` directly as scripts, which predictably fails with Error 500:

```
Error message:
End of script output before headers: index.php
```

What's wrong exactly?

How do I make Apache run

`php index.php`

instead of

`php php`

(i.e. quite probably `php php index.php`)

Comment: It might take less time and effort to modernize the web app.

Comment: While I agree with Micheal, I decided to try to replicate your environment just for the fun of it.
I can't reproduce your problem. I added the four lines (`Addtype`, `ScriptAlias`, `Action`) along with a `Require all granted` directive for the PHP bin directory to my apache.conf and the PHP scripts work. The problem must be somewhere else, what you didn't include in your question.

Comment: Thanks @GeraldSchneider. I have added info on a hack solution to finagle the environment variables, I don't understand why it should be needed though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Apache documentation for handlers](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/handler.html#examples) says the originally requested document is pointed to by the PATH_TRANSLATED environment variable. It doesn't mention SCRIPT_FILENAME.

The [CGI RFC 3875](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3875) also doesn't mention SCRIPT_FILENAME. One the other hand, your examples show that the php-cgi you are using expects the name of the PHP file in SCRIPT_FILENAME. This seems to be relying on undefined behavior.

Note that PHP 4.4.9 is quite old, while the Apache server you are using is probably newer. So it is possible that the Apache from that time passed the name of the script file (also) in SCRIPT_FILENAME, and the behavior has changed since then.

You don't need perl to assign the environment variable, a simple scell script will also do, but use what you are comfortable with.

```
#!/bin/sh

SCRIPT_FILENAME=$PATH_TRANSLATED exec /usr/local/php-4.4.9/bin/php
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to be Deep Archeology right there, right out of a Vernor Vinge novel. Additionally, the simple call to `phpinfo()` which worked well in a fresh virtual host with the modifications described refused to work when surrounded by a PHPNuke site. (Don't ask). Also PHP4 connections are refused by MariaDB because the client uses Ancient Protocols. We will be looking for another solution. I mark this as a solution, gotta spend the bounty...

Comment: I suppose you have a reason to use such an old version of PHP. I also have some older applications (although not that old, PHP 5.3) that I copied to a virtual machine together with the matching Apache, and have a current Apache as proxy for the domain on the virtual machine (and other VHosts with current PHP). The modern Apache hopefully helps against vulnerabilities, and if not, they are restricted to the Apache inside the VM.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely crazy but I have found the following solution:

Create a script `redirect.pl` (which can also be a small binary of course) to "wrap" the `php` executable (note that there is no `php-cgi` in PHP 4.4.9).

The script is invoked from *Apache httpd* by:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php        .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

ScriptAlias /outsidephp             /usr/local/php-4.4.9/bin
Action      application/x-httpd-php /outsidephp/redirect.pl
```

The full pathname to the script is `/usr/local/php-4.4.9/bin/redirect.pl`; it just does this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $phpfile = $ENV{PATH_TRANSLATED};
my $phpexe  = $ENV{SCRIPT_FILENAME};

$ENV{SCRIPT_FILENAME} = $phpfile;

exec "/usr/local/php-4.4.9/bin/php";
```

Why the above? The environment variables that *Apache Httpd* sets for the CGI executable if `index.php` is requested are:

```
PATH_TRANSLATED = /var/www/html/myserver.example.com/phphere/index.php
SCRIPT_FILENAME = /usr/local/php-4.4.9/bin/php
```

Empirically this makes `php` just execute itself i.e. `php` assumes that `SCRIPT_FILENAME` contains the filename of PHP script, with some justification.

Therefore, we need the script above to set the value of `SCRIPT_FILENAME` to the value of `PATH_TRANSLATED`.

Now the question is, why does *Apache Httpd* set the value of `SCRIPT_FILENAME` the way it does?